# SQL Server select query based on logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table :

```
ID  Package
1   T
1   E
1   B
1   F
2   E
3   E
3   F
4   F
5   B
5   F
```

I need the below output table :

```
ID  Package
1   T
2   E
3   E
4   F
5   B
```

Priority list for the packages : T, E, B, F .
Basically the logic should be as below :

1. If multiple entries of ID is there then select the packages based on priority list
2. If single entry, then pick it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                                   ORDER BY CASE Package WHEN 'T' THEN 1
                                                         WHEN 'E' THEN 2
                                                         WHEN 'B' THEN 3
                                                         WHEN 'F' THEN 4 END) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT ID, Package
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, cant this be done without WITH ? just in select query pls ?

Comment: You may just replace `cte` in the query on the bottom with the contents of the CTE, i.e. use `SELECT ID, Package FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() ...) t WHERE rn = 1`

Comment: You can shorted the `ORDER BY` logic to `CHARINDEX('TEBF', package)`.